# How rabbitmq internally stores message and how to retrieve back in original form?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, hbase, pika

I am trying to publish rabbitmq message with following python script--

```
import findspark
findspark.init("/home/spark/spark-2.2.0")
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pika
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()
channel.queue_declare(queue='task_queue_durable', durable=True)
message="Hello_Hbase!"
channel.basic_publish(exchange='',routing_key='queue1',body=message)
print(" [x] Sent %r" % message)
connection.close()
```

next, this is the subscriber script. In this script I want to retrieve the message from `routing_queue='queue1'` and want to store that message somewhere else..

```
import findspark
findspark.init("/home/spark/spark-2.2.0")
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

import time
import pika
import happybase
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()
channel.queue_declare(queue='queue1', durable=True)
print(' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C')

connection = happybase.Connection(host='localhost', port=9090)
table = connection.table('blogpost')
print(connection.tables())

    def callback(ch, method, body):
        print(" [x] Received %r" % body)
        time.sleep(body.count('.'))
        print(" [x] Done")
        ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)
        #return(body)

channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
body=channel.basic_consume( callback,queue='queue1') 
print(body) ## here it is giving some encrypted msg, how to retrieve in original form
# here in the body,I am getting this - ctag1.587a9ab83301436195fc3f653c2f6db0 
table.put('1', {'post:status': body})
print("hbase insertion done")
#channel.start_consuming()
```

Can someone let me know how to retrieve msg from rabbitmq queue in its original form?

Comment: It would be helpful if you show us the message you have received.

Comment: print(body)here i am getting this -  ctag1.587a9ab83301436195fc3f653c2f6db0

Answer (score 0):

`basic_consume` doesn't return the body of the message.

That is accessible within the callback function, as the `body` parameter, which you are already correctly using. You should do your database manipulation there too.